# handle click on nontransparent area of imageView only ios

Tags: ios, image

I am suppose to detect touch on various sections of image. For eg, I am having an image of a body which have different sections for chest , head, legs. So if user taps on hand only the hand section should only receive touch not the transparent area in the image.And the sections share some amount of same frame[image]

[image: Body image with diifrent section]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using SVG images for the same and the check touch position is inside of the path drawn. Used pocketSVG for reading SVG images 
here is the link for same

https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG

Answer (score 1):

This code, which i had adapted for me from another stackoverflow user, can get you the alpha value of the touched point:

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

//values doubled because image is retina
float width = image.size.width*2.0;
float height = image.size.height*2.0;
float x = point.x*2.0;
float y = point.y*2.0;

if (x < 0 ||
    y < 0 ||
    x > width ||
    y > height)
    return nil;

int pixelInfo = ((width  * y) + x ) * 4; // for png

UInt8 alpha = data[pixelInfo + 3];
CFRelease(pixelData);
```

You can use this to check if the user clicked in a transparent area or not.

As for detecting the different areas (hand, leg, head, etc) i would suggest defining some approximate rectangles for each section, and use this to check if the touch point is inside any of them:

```
    CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);
```